# Simple xpath get data from domdocument

Tags: xml, xpath, domdocument

I know this is quite basic but i just can't seem to find any good info on domdocuemnt and xpath.

How I can easily get the values of the error (as a string) using domdocument and xpath?

```
<Rows Items="1">
<Row Error="2" Description="Unknown key" Cause="Unknown key" Resolution="" />
</Rows>
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can easily get the values of the error (as a string) using
>   domdocument and xpath?

**Use**:

```
/*/Row/@*
```

**The above XPAth expression selects all attributes** (`Error`, `Description`, `Cause` and `Resolution`) of the single `Raw` element in the provided XML document. You'll need to iterate (using your PL) through the returned node-list if you want to concatenate/format these into a single string.

**The attributes may be selected individually** with a separate XPath expression for each of them:

```
/*/Row/@Error

/*/Row/@Description

/*/Row/@Cause

/*/Row/@Resolution
```

Answer (score 1):

Some XPaths, which you could find useful.

All the errors:

```
/Rows/Row/@Error
```

A specific row by its error:

```
/Rows/Row[@Error=2]
```

A description of a specific row:

```
/Rows/Row/@Description[../@Error=2]
```